# Chainerのサンプルコードについて

Tags: python, chainer

ChainerのサンプルコードにあるMNIST 画像データの学習を行うプログラム
https://github.com/pfnet/chainer/blob/master/examples/mnist/train_mnist.py
を参考に自分でプログラムを書いたのですが、学習が始まって数秒のところでエラーが出てしまいます。
エラーの内容が

```
'int' object is not callable
```

これが発生しているのが、

```
self.trainer.run()
```

という部分でした。以下に全プログラムを掲載します。

main.py

```
from __future__ import print_function

import MultiLayerPerceptron

import chainer
import chainer.functions as F
import chainer.links as L
from chainer import training
from chainer.training import extensions

GPU = 0
UNIT = 1000
O_UNIT = 10
BACTHSIZE = 100
EPOCH = 20
OUT = 'result'
RESUME = ''



def main():

    setParams = MultiLayerPerceptron.SetParams(UNIT, O_UNIT, GPU, BACTHSIZE, EPOCH, OUT, RESUME)
    setParams.SetGPU()
    setParams.SetOptimizer()
    setParams.SetMNISTData()
    setParams.SetTrainer()
    setParams.SetExtension()
    setParams.RunTrainer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

MultiLayerPerceptron.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import chainer
import chainer.links as L
import chainer.functions as F
from chainer import training
from chainer.training import extensions


class MLP(chainer.Chain):

    def __init__(self,n_units,n_out):
        super(MLP, self).__init__(
            l1=L.Linear(None,n_units),
            l2=L.Linear(None,n_units),
            l3=L.Linear(None,n_out),
        )
    def __call__(self,x):
        h1 = F.relu(self.l1(x))
        h2 = F.relu(self.l2(h1))
        return self.l3(h2)

class SetParams:
    def __init__(self,unit, o_unit, gpu,batchSize,epoch,out,resume):
        self.model = L.Classifier(MLP(unit, o_unit))
        self.gpu = gpu
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.epoch = epoch
        self.out = out
        self.resume = resume
        self.optimiszer = None
        self.train = None
        self.test = None
        self.trainIter = None
        self.testIter = None
        self.trainer = None

    #GPUの設定       
    def SetGPU(self):
        if self.gpu >= 0:
            chainer.cuda.get_device(self.gpu).use()
            self.model.to_gpu()
        print "Set GPU - OK"

    #最適化関数の設定
    def SetOptimizer(self):
        self.optimizer = chainer.optimizers.Adam()
        self.optimizer.setup(self.model)
        print "Set Optimizer - OK"

    #MNIST画像データの取得
    def SetMNISTData(self):
        self.train,self.test = chainer.datasets.get_mnist() #ラベル付きデータセット、1次元、データType=float32、ラベルType=int32
        #ミニバッチの設定
        self.trainIter = chainer.iterators.SerialIterator(self.train, self.batchSize) #繰り返し有り、順番入れ替えあり
        self.testIter = chainer.iterators.SerialIterator(self.test, self.batchSize, False, False) #繰り返しなし、順番入れ替えなし
        print "Set MNIST Image - OK"


    def SetTrainer(self):
        self.updater = training.StandardUpdater(self.trainIter, self.optimizer, device = self.gpu)
        self.trainer = training.Trainer(self.updater, (self.epoch, 'epoch'), out = self.out) #*****　不明　*****

    def SetExtension(self):
        self.trainer.extend(extensions.Evaluator(self.testIter, self.model, self.gpu))
        self.trainer.extend(extensions.dump_graph('main/loss'))
        self.trainer.extend(extensions.snapshot(), trigger=(self.epoch, 'epoch'))
        self.trainer.extend(extensions.LogReport())
        self.trainer.extend(extensions.PrintReport(
            ['epoch', 'main/loss', 'validaton/main/loss', 
             'main/accuracy', 'validation/main/accuracy', 'elapsed_time']))
        self.trainer.extend(extensions.ProgressBar())
        print "Set Extension - OK"

    def RunTrainer(self):
        if self.resume:
            chainer.serializers.load_npz(self.resume, self.trainer)
        self.trainer.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Evaluatorの引数が間違っています。
可変の引数を取るものはちゃんと引数名を指定しないと意図しない変数を渡すことになります。
`self.trainer.extend(extensions.Evaluator(self.testIter, self.model, device =self.gpu))`